# How do I use Tensorflow tf.nn.conv2 to make a convolutional layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

With `tf.nn.conv2d`, you can perform a convolutional operation on a tensor. E.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32)

filters = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 3, 3, 10))

tf.nn.conv2d(input=x, filters=filters, strides=1, padding='VALID')
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 224, 222, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[2.1705112, 1.2065555, 1.7674012, ..., 1.705754 , 1.3659815,
          1.7028458],
         [2.0048866, 1.4835871, 1.2038497, ..., 1.8981357, 1.4605963,
          2.148876 ],
         [2.4999123, 1.856892 , 1.0806457, ..., 2.270382 , 1.5633923,
          1.5280294],
         ...,
         [3.2492838, 1.9597337, 2.3294296, ..., 2.8038855, 2.1928523,
          3.065394 ],
         [2.5742679, 1.4919059, 1.4522426, ..., 2.158071 , 1.9074411,
          2.2769275],
         [2.8084617, 2.315342 , 1.554437 , ..., 2.2483544, 2.0936842,
          1.997768 ]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

But the filters aren't learned, nor are they adjusted automatically. They need to be specified in advance. How can I use this operation in a custom Keras layer with weights that learn?

Answer (score 3):

When you subclass a [`tf.keras.layers.Layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers), the model will track all [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) inside as trainable variables. What you then need to do is create a `tf.Variable` with the shape of the convolutional filter, and these will adjust to the task (i.e. learn) during training. The filters need this input shape:

```
(filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels)
```

This `tf.keras.layers.Layer` object will behave exactly like a Keras convolutional layer in a CNN:

```
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, padding, strides, activation,
                 kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, use_bias):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.activation = activation
        self.padding = padding
        self.kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
        self.bias_initializer = bias_initializer
        self.strides = strides
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.w = None
        self.b = None

    def build(self, input_shape):
        *_, n_channels = input_shape
        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=self.kernel_initializer(shape=(*self.kernel_size,
                                                         n_channels,
                                                         self.filters),
                                 dtype='float32'), trainable=True)
        if self.use_bias:
            self.b = tf.Variable(
                initial_value=self.bias_initializer(shape=(self.filters,), dtype='float32'),
                trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        x =  tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, filters=self.w, strides=self.strides, padding=self.padding)
        if self.use_bias:
            x = x + self.b
        x = self.activation(x)
        return x
```

You can see that the weights are the filters of the `tf.nn.conv2d` operation, which are `tf.Variable`, and so they are weights that will be updated by model training.

If you run this entire script, you will see that it performs the exact same task as the Keras convolutional layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(42)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))

rescale = lambda x, y: (tf.divide(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), 255), y)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.map(rescale).\
    shuffle(128, reshuffle_each_iteration=False, seed=11).\
    batch(8).\
    prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.map(rescale).\
    shuffle(128, reshuffle_each_iteration=False, seed=11).\
    batch(8).\
    prefetch(AUTOTUNE)


class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, padding, strides, activation,
                 kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, use_bias):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.activation = activation
        self.padding = padding
        self.kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
        self.bias_initializer = bias_initializer
        self.strides = strides
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.w = None
        self.b = None

    def build(self, input_shape):
        *_, n_channels = input_shape
        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=self.kernel_initializer(shape=(*self.kernel_size,
                                                         n_channels,
                                                         self.filters),
                                 dtype='float32'), trainable=True)
        if self.use_bias:
            self.b = tf.Variable(
                initial_value=self.bias_initializer(shape=(self.filters,), 
                                                    dtype='float32'),
                trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        x =  tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, filters=self.w, strides=self.strides, 
                          padding=self.padding)
        if self.use_bias:
            x = x + self.b
        x = self.activation(x)
        return x


class ModelWithCustomConvLayer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, conv_layer):
        super(ModelWithCustomConvLayer, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = conv_layer(filters=16,
                                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                strides=(1, 1),
                                activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                padding='VALID',
                                kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42),
                                bias_initializer=tf.initializers.Zeros(),
                                use_bias=True)
        self.maxp = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.conv2 = conv_layer(filters=32,
                                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                strides=(1, 1),
                                activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                padding='VALID',
                                kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42),
                                bias_initializer=tf.initializers.Zeros(),
                                use_bias=True)
        self.flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu',
                            kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax',
                            kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42))

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.maxp(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxp(x)
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        return x


custom = ModelWithCustomConvLayer(CustomLayer)
custom.compile(loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer='adam',
               metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())
custom.build(input_shape=next(iter(train_ds))[0].shape)
custom.summary()

normal = ModelWithCustomConvLayer(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D)
normal.compile(loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer='adam',
               metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())
normal.build(input_shape=next(iter(train_ds))[0].shape)
normal.summary()

history_custom = custom.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=25,
                            steps_per_epoch=10, verbose=0)
history_normal = normal.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds, epochs=25,
                            steps_per_epoch=10, verbose=0)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(history_custom.history['loss'], color='red', alpha=.5, lw=4)
plt.plot(history_custom.history['sparse_categorical_accuracy'],
         color='blue', alpha=.5, lw=4)
plt.plot(history_custom.history['val_loss'], color='green', alpha=.5, lw=4)
plt.plot(history_custom.history['val_sparse_categorical_accuracy'],
         color='orange', alpha=.5, lw=4)

plt.plot(history_normal.history['loss'], ls=':', color='red')
plt.plot(history_normal.history['sparse_categorical_accuracy'], ls=':',
         color='blue')
plt.plot(history_normal.history['val_loss'], ls=':', color='green')
plt.plot(history_normal.history['val_sparse_categorical_accuracy'], ls=':',
         color='orange')
plt.legend(list(map(lambda x: 'custom_' + x, list(history_custom.history.keys()))) +
           list(map(lambda x: 'keras_' + x, list(history_normal.history.keys()))))
plt.title('Custom Conv Layer vs Keras Conv Layer')
plt.show()
```

The dotted lines represent the model performance when the Keras layer is used, and the full line is when my custom layer using `tf.nn.conv2d` is used. They are **the exact same thing** when the seed is set.

[image]

Comment: Great. One big motivation is to use dilate and stride at the same time, which seems to work with tf.nn.conv2d, but not with keras Conv2D. For some reasons, keras has not implemented that.