# TensorFlow Conv2D with kernel as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Is there a layer or function in TensorFlow that acts exactly like `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` except the kernel/filter is an input to the layer? I am aware that `tf.nn.conv2d` accepts the filter weights as an input, but it assumes that the weights are the same for all samples in a batch. In my case, I want the filter to be different for each batch. (There is the obvious solution of making the batch size 1, but that is not ideal)

I ask because I am trying to create a one-shot learning model, and I haven't had much success with Siamese networks when there is a large input space (>150 samples), so I would like to make a meta-learning model instead. If there is an alternative to Siamese networks or meta-learning for this problem, I would also be grateful to hear it.

Comment: What do you mean *the kernel/filter is an input to the layer*?

Comment: Normally for Conv2D you would only give an image, or a 4D tensor [batch_size, x, y, channel]. I want it to take two inputs. The usual 4D tensor, but also the weights, shape [batch_size, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels].

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do but maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65542469/how-do-i-use-tensorflow-tf-nn-conv2-to-make-a-convolutional-layer